# Where to store functions for use in both controller and view?

Tags: zend-framework

I have some functions in my project as action helpers, and they are used within the controller. For example, a function which manipulates a string in a certain way. Ordinarily, I am pulling data from the database in the controller, manipulating the whole dataset in the controller (and in the process applying the action helper to the data) before sending it to the view. However, in some controllers, the dataset can be sent straight to the view without significant modification. I want to apply the same function to data within the view instead because this is more efficient. I only want to define the function in one place, and action helper functions are apparently not supposed to be used within the view.

So the question is, from a best practice point of view, where am I supposed to store functions which may be used in either the controller or the view?

Comment: As per the MVC , the manipulation of data in Controllers in not  best practice. This process needs to be done in models. And regarding having common function, In models you can create new model which will have these kind of function which can be accessed in either view or controller of anywhere by calling for example model_classname::function_name().

Comment: I thought the argument regarding where the majority of business data should be kept is still running. I have no presentational code outside the view, and no database statements outside the model, where the rest fits is debatable it seems to me.

Anyway, what I'm talking about is a piece of data formatting that is currently performed in the view as a helper, and I now need to access in a controller when the view is not rendered (file downloads for example).